# Выполнение метода по таймеру

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Хотел бы задать следующий вопрос - предположим, есть некая Windows-служба, постоянно работающая. Как можно сделать так, чтобы каждый день в определенное время эта служба выполняла некий метод, а все остальное время тихо сиделе себе в памяти? Заранее спасибо

Comment: А чем Task Scheduler (Планировщик Задач) не подходит?

Comment: наверное тем что я о нем не слышал)

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Scheduler

Comment: ах вы об этом.нет, к сожалению, это не то, речь идет именно о написании службы и вызове этой службой метода самой службы или какого-то класса

Comment: В службе ставите на таймер, допустим,  каждую минуту проверять если нужно время наступило - вызывать нужный вам метод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делается с помощью таймера:

```
public sealed class DailyTimer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Timer timer;

    public DailyTimer(double hours, double minutes, TimerCallback callback)
    {
        timer = new Timer(callback);
        Change(hours, minutes);
    }

    private static void Change(DailyTimer dailyTimer, double hours, double minutes)
    {
        var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        var nextAlarm = currentTime.Date.AddHours(hours).AddMinutes(minutes);
        if (nextAlarm < currentTime)
        {
            nextAlarm = nextAlarm.AddDays(1);
        }
        dailyTimer.timer.Change(nextAlarm.Subtract(currentTime), TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
    }

    public void Change(double hours, double minutes)
    {
        Change(this, hours, minutes);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```